# Remove html tags from rich text field in lwc UI

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, developer

I have one rich text field on obj which holds html content.
when i am using
`<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={richtxtfield}`,
its displaying html tags also in the UI.
**how can I remove those html tags? pls help**

ex.

Field value in SF:
<h2.>ABCD</h2.>
//.. given to format it

JS file:

```js
@wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS}) 
    wiredEventData({error,data}) {
    if(data){
       this.richtxtfield=getFieldValue(data,richtext);
    }
}
```

html:

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={richtxtfield}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to remove html tags from value .

```
.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
```

[image]